# I am not able to install nodejs 8 on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, updating

I have nodejs version `v4.2.6` on my ubuntu machine. If I try to upgrade to `v8` or try to remove and install `v8`, then still `v4.2.6` is installed on my machine.

I removed the older version.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs 
sudo apt-get remove npm 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

Then installed v8:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But still, I have node `v4.2.6`

Can you please tell me how to upgrade to `v8`.

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO, but anyway: what does `which npm` or `which node` say after you execute all those remove commands?

Comment: can you print `PATH`, ie `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nvm to update your node version on Ubuntu.

1. [Install nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installation)
2. Follow [David Walsh blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)

---

*At any given time you can switch to another with use:*

```
nvm use 0.12
```

*If you want to check out what versions of Node.js are installed on your machine, you can use the ls option:*

```
nvm ls

/*
        v0.10.26
        v0.10.36
->      v0.12.7
        v4.2.1
        system
*/
```

*If you're done with a version and want it gone, you can do that too:*

```
nvm uninstall 0.10*
```